# how to separate the starting text and ending text using sub string in java script?

Tags: javascript, substring

I have strings that have the text at the start and at the end but in the between there is an image src

These are the different types of string given below

```
SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____::ad4d7360-9c6c-44fa-bcbb-0db7e671e036.png____SERVER_UPLOAD_END Execuse Me

this was the url SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____::5e2650c2-728c-40af-99a4-eb100c432091.png____SERVER_UPLOAD_END click here to view details

SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____::ad4d7360-9c6c-44fa-bcbb-0db7e671e036.png____SERVER_UPLOAD_END

SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____::68d37b07-d694-47af-a16a-8adbe400ac67.png____SERVER_UPLOAD_END Hector where are you Hello world how are you
```

I tried  this code

```
var element = result.find(a =>a.includes("____SERVER_UPLOAD_END"));
var res = element.substring(element.lastIndexOf(":") + 1,element.lastIndexOf("____SERVER_UPLOAD_END"));
console.log(res)
```

but it gives me following result

```
ad4d7360-9c6c-44fa-bcbb-0db7e671e036.png
5e2650c2-728c-40af-99a4-eb100c432091.png
ad4d7360-9c6c-44fa-bcbb-0db7e671e036.png
68d37b07-d694-47af-a16a-8adbe400ac67.png
```

Expected Result is

```
ad4d7360-9c6c-44fa-bcbb-0db7e671e036.png Excuse ME
this wa the url 5e2650c2-728c-40af-99a4-eb100c432091.png click here to view details
ad4d7360-9c6c-44fa-bcbb-0db7e671e036.png
68d37b07-d694-47af-a16a-8adbe400ac67.png Hector where are you Hello world how are you
```

how to get also text that come at the start and at the end of img path and also come between the img path?

Any Help would be appreciated thanks in Advance

Comment: So you want `element.replace("SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____::",ImagePath)` instead of prepending the `ImagePath` to the entire string?

Comment: i mean to say that at the start of string there must be the text and after that url is concatenate along with img path and at the end the string text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```js
const str = `SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____::ad4d7360-9c6c-44fa-bcbb-0db7e671e036.png____SERVER_UPLOAD_END Execuse Me
this was the url SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____::5e2650c2-728c-40af-99a4-eb100c432091.png____SERVER_UPLOAD_END click here to view details
SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____::ad4d7360-9c6c-44fa-bcbb-0db7e671e036.png____SERVER_UPLOAD_END
SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____::68d37b07-d694-47af-a16a-8adbe400ac67.png____SERVER_UPLOAD_END Hector where are you Hello world how are you`

const texts = str.split("\n")
  .map(line => line
       .replace("SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____::",`<img src="https://www.web.com/`)
       .replace("____SERVER_UPLOAD_END",'" alt="image"/>'))

console.log(texts)
```

regex could be used, but the above replace is simpler to read because you are actually just removing the file path indicators

```js
const str = `SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____::ad4d7360-9c6c-44fa-bcbb-0db7e671e036.png____SERVER_UPLOAD_END Execuse Me
this was the url SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____::5e2650c2-728c-40af-99a4-eb100c432091.png____SERVER_UPLOAD_END click here to view details
SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____::ad4d7360-9c6c-44fa-bcbb-0db7e671e036.png____SERVER_UPLOAD_END
SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____::68d37b07-d694-47af-a16a-8adbe400ac67.png____SERVER_UPLOAD_END Hector where are you Hello world how are you`

const texts = str.split("\n")
  .map(line => {
    [, text1, url, text2] = line.match(/(.*?)?(?:SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____::)(.*?)(?:____SERVER_UPLOAD_END)(.*)?/);
    return `${text1 || ""}<img src="https://www.web.com/${url}" alt="image" />${text2 ||""}`
  })

console.log(texts)
```

Comment: @Umair I added the image tag

Comment: Do you need a link with the second text in the link? What if ther is no second text?

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expression and groups delimited by `()` you can access different parts of the string more elegant. Thus:

```
regex=/(.*)SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____::([^_]*)____SERVER_UPLOAD_END(.*)/
var result = regex.exec(a)
// result[0] contains all matched string 
// result[1] contains all before SERVER_UPLOAD
// result[2] contains the name of the file
// result[3] contains all after UPLOAD_END
```

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and show how your code is executed. `exec` is not that simple to handle - In this case, just removing the path indicators is simpler than stitching together the results of an exec

Comment: See my version. I am using `/(.*?)?(?:SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____::)(.*?)(?:____SERVER_UPLOAD_END)(.*)?/`

Answer (score -1):

If `url is SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____::5e2650c2-728c-40af-99a4eb100c432091.png____SERVER_UPLOAD_END click here` is the entire string value, I would try this:

```js
var element = "url is SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____::5e2650c2-728c-40af-99a4eb100c432091.png____SERVER_UPLOAD_END click here";
var result = element.substring(
  element.lastIndexOf(":") + 1,
  element.lastIndexOf("____SERVER_UPLOAD_END click here")
);

console.log(result);
```

Result will be `5e2650c2-728c-40af-99a4eb100c432091.png`

Comment: my expected result is this:- url is https://www.web.com/5e2650c2-728c-40af-99a4-eb100c432091.png click here

Comment: This will also fail if there is a `:` in the text after the file

Comment: <a class="" href="#" src="https://www.web.com/ad4d7360-9c6c-44fa-bcbb-0db7e671e036.png Execuse Me">Click Here </a> how to remove ```Excuse Me```from src